# Is the bug about kernels increasing temperature fixed?

Tags: kernel

I've read about a bug in the first versions of kernel 2.6.35 that causes the temperature to increase above the normal. Does anyone knows if it is already corrected?

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is a bug in the kernel, according to this [lauchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lm-sensors-3/+bug/606733). People are seeing this a lot, although they say the temperature **feels the same**. It is probably a bug that should be fixed soon. You don't have to worry about it. If you update your ubuntu installation a feel the machine is getting hotter, not just what is said by the lm sensors, than you could downgrade the kernel to a "safer" version.

Answer (score 0):

You may be talking about this issue: http://smackerelofopinion.blogspot.com/2010/09/sensors-reporting-hot-cpu-in-maverick.html

The takeaway is that it may just be a change in how the temperature is reported, not an actual change in how hot the system is.  To test if this is so, see if the output of:

```
cat /sys/devices/platform/coretemp*/temp1_crit
```

has changed from 10.04 to 10.10. If so, your system will report hotter temperatures, but it will not actually be running hotter.